# Highlight a text in word document in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, highlight

I am able to search/highlight a particular word in a word document with my code. But below is the problem I am facing.

If the search word is "it" then it searches for "it" and also in w"it"nessed. I want to search only the word "it". How do i solve this issue?

```
 private int FindLoop(Word._Application wordApp, object text,
                            Word._Document aDoc,
                            object aComment, out List<string> OccuranceList,
                            bool insertComment)
    {

        int intFound = 0;
        //object start = 0;
        //object end = 1;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        object myfile = saveFileDialog.FileName;

        Word.Range rng = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Range(ref missing, ref missing);




        object readOnly = true;
        //object isVisible = true;
        object isVisible = false;
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        string fname = textBox1.Text;


        object matchWholeWord = true;

        OccuranceList = new List<string>();
        object[] Parameters;
        Parameters = new object[15];
        Parameters[0] = text;
        Parameters[1] = missing;
        Parameters[2] = missing;
        Parameters[3] = missing;
        Parameters[4] = missing;
        Parameters[5] = missing;
        Parameters[6] = missing;
        Parameters[7] = missing;
        Parameters[8] = missing;
        Parameters[9] = text;
        Parameters[10] = missing;
        Parameters[11] = missing;
        Parameters[12] = missing;
        Parameters[13] = missing;
        Parameters[14] = missing;
        bool found = false;



        {
            try
            {

                found = (bool)rng.Find.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, rng.Find, Parameters);





            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Find Loop", ex.Message);
            }





            //while (rng.Find.Found)
            while (found)
            {



                intFound++;
                if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (fname.ToString().EndsWith("doc") || fname.ToString().EndsWith("docx"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (rng.Text.Trim() == text.ToString())
                            {



                                // Add a new document 
                                aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fname, ref oMissing,
                                                               ref readOnly, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                                               ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                                               ref oMissing, ref isVisible, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                                               ref oMissing, ref oMissing);



                                rng.Font.Bold = 1;
                                rng.HighlightColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkRed;
                            }

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }

                    }


                }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some wildcards to text you search. In you situation text to find will be: `<it>` instead of `it`. Referring to your code it should be something like this:

```
Parameters[0] = String.Format("<{0}>"; text);
```

Moreover, you will need to set wildcards parameters to true:

```
Parameters[3] = true;
```

For more information check [this link](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm).

Comment: Am facing issues with cases. I need to search for it without considering case sensitivity.

Comment: try to set to true: `Parameters[1]=true;`